# Abaqus error: THE INDEPENDENT VARIABLES MUST BE ARRANGED IN ASCENDING ORDER

Tags: abaqus

**Problem**: Job does not run

**Error I get**: Error in job: THE INDEPENDENT VARIABLES MUST BE ARRANGED IN ASCENDING ORDER, Job: Analysis Input File Processor aborted due to errors.

**My input file**: (note: I have shortened the +7000 lines of the input file code by replacing node, element and material model plastic data with three dots '...' in the code below)

```
*Heading
** Job name: Job-name Model name: Model-1
** Generated by: Abaqus/CAE 6.14-1
*Preprint, echo=NO, model=NO, history=NO, contact=NO
**
** PARTS
**
*Part, name=specimen
*Node
      1,  0.225999996, 0.0120000001, 0.00800000038
      2,  0.225999996, 0.0120000001, 0.0280000009
...
  36854,  0.145090953, 0.00200000009, 0.0270000007
  36855,  0.145090953, 0.00100000005, 0.0270000007
*Element, type=C3D8R
   1,   194,  1981, 10731,  1673,     1,    41,  1141,   106
   2,  1981,  1982, 10732, 10731,    41,    42,  1142,  1141
 ...
32159, 36854, 36855, 10730, 10729,  8331,  8332,   845,   846
32160, 36855, 10422,  1126, 10730,  8332,   948,    33,   845
*Nset, nset=Set-1, generate
     1,  36855,      1
*Elset, elset=Set-1, generate
     1,  32160,      1
*Nset, nset=Set-2
     1,     2,     3,     4,     5,     6,     7,     8,     9,    10,    11,    12,    13,    14,    15,    16
    17,    18,    19,    20,    21,    22,    23,    24,    25,    26,    27,    28,    29,    30,    31,    32
    33,    34,    35,    36,    37,    38,    39,    40,    41,    42,    43,    44,    45,    46,    47,    48 
 ...
 21988, 21989, 21990, 21991, 21992, 21993, 21994, 21995, 21996, 21997, 21998, 21999, 22000, 22001, 22002, 22003
 22004, 22005, 22006, 22007, 22008, 22009, 22010, 22011, 22012, 22013, 22014, 22015, 22016
*Elset, elset=Set-3, generate
  6961,  13680,      1
** Section: section 1
*Solid Section, elset=Set-2, material=material 1
,
** Section: section 2
*Solid Section, elset=Set-3, material=material 2
,
*End Part
**  
**
** ASSEMBLY
**
*Assembly, name=Assembly
**  
*Instance, name=specimen-1, part=specimen
      -0.163,           0.,       -0.028
*End Instance
**  
*Node
      1, -0.133000001, 0.00600000005, -0.00999999978
*Node
      2,  0.202999994, 0.00600000005, -0.00999999978
*Nset, nset=ROI, instance=specimen-1
    2,    5,    9,   12,   15,   16,   18,   20,  206,  207,  208,  209,  210,  211,  212,  213
  214,  215,  216,  268,  269,  270,  271,  272,  273,  274,  275,  276,  277,  278,  279,  280
...
 6042, 6043, 6044, 6045, 6046, 6047, 6048, 6049, 6050, 6051, 6052, 6053, 6054, 6055, 6056, 6057
 6058, 6059, 6060, 6061, 6062
*Elset, elset=ROI, instance=specimen-1, generate
  3601,  17021,     20
*Nset, nset=Set-40
 1,
*Nset, nset=Set-43
 2,
*Nset, nset="fiexd point"
 1,
*Nset, nset=m_Set-39
 1,
*Nset, nset=m_Set-42
 2,
*Nset, nset="moving point"
 2,
*Elset, elset=_s_Surf-1_S5, internal, instance=specimen-1
 23989, 23990, 23991, 23992, 23993, 23994, 23995, 23996, 23997, 23998, 23999, 24000, 24229, 24230, 24231, 24232
 24233, 24234, 24235, 24236, 24237, 24238, 24239, 24240, 24469, 24470, 24471, 24472, 24473, 24474, 24475, 24476
 ...
 28073, 28074, 28075, 28076, 28077, 28078, 28079, 28080, 28309, 28310, 28311, 28312, 28313, 28314, 28315, 28316
 28317, 28318, 28319, 28320, 28549, 28550, 28551, 28552, 28553, 28554, 28555, 28556, 28557, 28558, 28559, 28560
*Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=s_Surf-1
_s_Surf-1_S5, S5
*Elset, elset=_s_Surf-2_S4, internal, instance=specimen-1, generate
 23772,  28560,     12
*Elset, elset=_s_Surf-2_S1, internal, instance=specimen-1, generate
 28321,  28560,      1
*Elset, elset=_s_Surf-2_S6, internal, instance=specimen-1, generate
 23761,  28549,     12
*Elset, elset=_s_Surf-2_S2, internal, instance=specimen-1, generate
 23761,  24000,      1
*Elset, elset=_s_Surf-2_S5, internal, instance=specimen-1
 23989, 23990, 23991, 23992, 23993, 23994, 23995, 23996, 23997, 23998, 23999, 24000, 24229, 24230, 24231, 24232
 24233, 24234, 24235, 24236, 24237, 24238, 24239, 24240, 24469, 24470, 24471, 24472, 24473, 24474, 24475, 24476
 ...
 28073, 28074, 28075, 28076, 28077, 28078, 28079, 28080, 28309, 28310, 28311, 28312, 28313, 28314, 28315, 28316
 28317, 28318, 28319, 28320, 28549, 28550, 28551, 28552, 28553, 28554, 28555, 28556, 28557, 28558, 28559, 28560
*Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=s_Surf-2
_s_Surf-2_S4, S4
_s_Surf-2_S1, S1
_s_Surf-2_S6, S6
_s_Surf-2_S2, S2
_s_Surf-2_S5, S5
*Elset, elset=_s_Surf-3_S1, internal, instance=specimen-1, generate
 22401,  22800,      1
*Elset, elset=_s_Surf-3_S2, internal, instance=specimen-1, generate
 18001,  18400,      1
*Elset, elset=_s_Surf-3_S6, internal, instance=specimen-1, generate
 18001,  22781,     20
*Elset, elset=_s_Surf-3_S4, internal, instance=specimen-1, generate
 18020,  22800,     20
*Elset, elset=_s_Surf-3_S5, internal, instance=specimen-1
 18381, 18382, 18383, 18384, 18385, 18386, 18387, 18388, 18389, 18390, 18391, 18392, 18393, 18394, 18395, 18396
 18397, 18398, 18399, 18400, 18781, 18782, 18783, 18784, 18785, 18786, 18787, 18788, 18789, 18790, 18791, 18792
 ...
 22389, 22390, 22391, 22392, 22393, 22394, 22395, 22396, 22397, 22398, 22399, 22400, 22781, 22782, 22783, 22784
 22785, 22786, 22787, 22788, 22789, 22790, 22791, 22792, 22793, 22794, 22795, 22796, 22797, 22798, 22799, 22800
*Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=s_Surf-3
_s_Surf-3_S1, S1
_s_Surf-3_S2, S2
_s_Surf-3_S6, S6
_s_Surf-3_S4, S4
_s_Surf-3_S5, S5
** Constraint: Constraint-1
*Coupling, constraint name=Constraint-1, ref node=m_Set-39, surface=s_Surf-2
*Kinematic
** Constraint: moving constraint
*Coupling, constraint name="moving constraint", ref node=m_Set-42, surface=s_Surf-3
*Kinematic
*End Assembly
*Amplitude, name=Amp-1
             0.,             0.1,             0.1,             0.2,             0.2,             0.3,             0.3,             0.4
            0.4,             0.5,             0.5,             0.6,             0.6,             0.7,             0.7,             0.8
            0.8,             0.9,             0.9,              1.
** 
** MATERIALS
** 
*Material, name=material 1
*Density
 76977.1,
*Elastic
 2e+11, 0.3
*Plastic
 2.30721e+08,         0.
  2.4123e+08, 0.00201691
...
  7.2869e+08,   0.373545
 8.85332e+08,   0.481661
*Material, name=material 2
*Density
 76977.1,
*Elastic
 1.9e+11, 0.3
*Plastic
 2.30277e+08,          0.
 2.40307e+08, 0.000138965
...
  5.3843e+08,   0.0729109
 9.58223e+08,    0.380958
** ----------------------------------------------------------------
** 
** STEP: Step-1
** 
*Step, name=Step-1, nlgeom=YES
*Static
0.1, 1., 1e-05, 0.1
** 
** BOUNDARY CONDITIONS
** 
** Name: fixed Type: Displacement/Rotation
*Boundary, amplitude=Amp-1
Set-40, 1, 1
Set-40, 2, 2
Set-40, 3, 3
** 
** LOADS
** 
** Name: Load-1   Type: Concentrated force
*Cload, amplitude=Amp-1
Set-43, 1, 100000.
** 
** OUTPUT REQUESTS
** 
*Restart, write, frequency=0
** 
** FIELD OUTPUT: F-Output-1
** 
*Output, field
*Node Output
CF, RF, U
*Element Output, directions=NO
LE, MISES, PE, PEEQ, PEMAG, S
** 
** HISTORY OUTPUT: H-Output-1
** 
*Output, history
*Node Output, nset="fiexd point"
RF1, 
*End Step
```

**My question**: does anyone know what I need to change in this input file to avoid the error?

Comment: look at the `*Plastic` tables , make sure there are no repeated stress values

Comment: @ agentp: I checked the plastic tables. There are no repeated stress values.

Comment: As a test delete the entire plastic section (s) to see if that is the source of the error.

Comment: Using spaces in material names seems like asking for trouble btw. Can't see why that wold cause that error though

Comment: @ agentp: when I delete the plastic definitions it works. It also works with the plastic definition of only the first material being defined (and the second material with only elastic definition). I double checked the (x,y) data points of the plastic definition of the second material but there were no mistakes in them.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Python?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the definition of the data lines for *Plastic keyword is incorrect. There is no possibility to define *Plastic feature as a table.
Check documentation for this keyword.
According to the documentation, for *Plastic you specified in the input file, first line must be:

> First line:
>
> 1. Yield stress.
> 2. Plastic strain.
> 3. Temperature.
> 4. First field variable.
> 5. Second field variable.
> 6. Etc., up to five field variables.

For all other modification of plastic feature, the first line is similar.

Comment: the form is ok, stress strain, the remaining items are optional